# When overriding HandleAuthenticateAsync Fail reason is lost c# .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, api, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've implemented an api key auth for my .net core api, and if an invalid key is found I return the following as mentioned in a tutorial:

`return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid API Key provided.");`

This seems to result in my override of HandleChallengeAsync being called:

```
    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            Response.ContentType = ProblemDetailsContentType;
            var problemDetails = new UnauthorizedProblemDetails();

            await Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(problemDetails));
        }
```

I'm confused of the purpose of passing the fail reason to the .Fail() call, as it doesn't seem available for me to return to the user. What is it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that from the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/33eb8ba552c7452f441e2a223457d39f271d01b7/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticateResult.cs) the `Failure` property is an `Exception`:

```
    public Exception Failure { get; protected set; }


    public static AuthenticateResult Fail(string failureMessage)
        => Fail(new Exception(failureMessage));
```

Since they are requiring an `Exception` for the failure, a message is required to new up the `Exception`. I can also see some [logging referencing](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b7e122fbac4207b003dc07f6101e50218be8ff21/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L153) this message:

```
    public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var target = ResolveTarget(Options.ForwardAuthenticate);
        if (target != null)
        {
            return await Context.AuthenticateAsync(target);
        }

        // Calling Authenticate more than once should always return the original value.
        var result = await HandleAuthenticateOnceAsync();
        if (result?.Failure == null)
        {
            var ticket = result?.Ticket;
            if (ticket?.Principal != null)
            {
                Logger.AuthenticationSchemeAuthenticated(Scheme.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.AuthenticationSchemeNotAuthenticated(Scheme.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.AuthenticationSchemeNotAuthenticatedWithFailure(Scheme.Name, result.Failure.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Oh I'm new to .net core keep forgetting all the source can be easily viewed on github, nice